# Is there a simpler way to change how a function works depending on inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a function that I want to do/output something different depending on what inputs I give it. I've made something useful with `if else` logic but not elegant and I suspect there might be a shorter/more elegant way of doing it. What are the alternatives to the `if else` on `None` methods I've made?

e.g.,

```
def foo (a=None, b=None, c=None):
    if a is None:
        raise ValueError("a cannot be None!")
    elif all([b is None, c is None]):
        x = operations
        return x
    elif c is None:
        x = operations
        y = operations
        return x, y
    elif b is None:
        x = operations
        z = operations
        return x, z
    elif all([b is not None, c is not None]):
        x = operations
        y = operations
        z = operations
        return x, y, z
```

Comment: Better is very subjective. Please outline specific conditions

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, I modified the text to address your critique.

Comment: There really are no alternatives.  `if`/`elif`/`else` is a fundamental operation.  Technically, I guess you could use the `match`/`case` that was added in Python 3.10, but I don't think that reads more clearly than this.

Comment: You could use a Boolean Algebra Solver online to simplify your boolean logic, so that _could_ help...

Comment: And I know this was just an example, but your second clause will never run.  If `a` is `None`, you'll always take the first clause and will never check the second.  Also, if you are doing `return` at the end of each clause, you don't really need `elif`.  `if` will do just as well.

Comment: Are you just matching against variants `is None`? Is the matching exhaustive? Is scalability a concern, i.e. do you need the fastest lookup or is scaling logarithmic/linear with the number of cases okay?

Comment: @TimRoberts, &MisterMiyagi, I've improved my example to more closely resemble the actual function I made and hopefully address the critiques you've made. I failed to represent that I am trying to return different **output** depending on what I input.

Comment: Please make sure that the example is at least internally consistent. Right now at least the second branch is unreachable.

Comment: Again, there's nothing wrong with this code.  It expresses what you want to express in a reasonable way.  Your final `elif` can of course be replaced by `else:`, but that's nit-picking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "better" and what you are trying to do inside your ifs and elifs but I myself am not a big fan of the code style in your example either. It can become hard to read and maintain.

There are languages that make this kind of thing easy, but unfortunately Python is not one of them. However, there are a few ways that I think are "better", depending on what you are trying to do.

1. Lots of elifs:

```
def show_food_description(food):
   if food == "apple":
      print("It's red and sweet")
   elif food == "banana":
      print("It's long and yellow")
   elif food == "kiwi":
      print("It's green and hairy")
   else:
      print("This food is unknown")
```

alternative:

```
def show_food_description(food):
   descriptions = {
      "apple": "It's red and sweet",
      "banana": "It's long and yellow",
      "kiwi": "It's green and hairy"
   }
   print(descriptions.get(food, "This food is unknown"))
```

2. Testing for equality with more than one value:

```
food = "apple"

if food == "apple" or food == "banana" or food == "kiwi":
   print("It's a fruit!")
```

alternative:

```
food = "apple"
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "kiwi"]

if food in fruits:
   print("It's a fruit!")
```

3. Execute different function

```
def add_one(x):
   return x + 1

def add_two(x):
   return x + 2

def add_three(x):
   return x + 3


def perform_operation(x, operation):
   if operation == "add_one":
      return add_one(x)
   if operation == "add_two":
      return add_two(x)
   if operation == "add_three":
      return add_three(x)
   else:
      raise Exception("Unknown operation")
```

alternative:

```
def add_one(x):
   return x + 1

def add_two(x):
   return x + 2

def add_three(x):
   return x + 3

def unknown_operation(x):
   raise Exception("Unknown operation")

def perform_operation(x, operation):
   operations = {
      "add_one": add_one,
      "add_two": add_two,
      "add_three": add_three
   }

   selected_operation = operations.get(operation, unknown_operation)
   return selected_operation(x)
```

It is also worth mentioning that in Python 3.10, there is a `match` statement available that is similar to `switch` statements in other languages. Here is an example on how to use it:

```
language = "Python"

match language:
   case "C": print("It's C")
   case "Python": print("It's Python")
   case _: print("It doesn't matter")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Python 3.10** installed you can use the **match-case**.
Please refer to *PEP 634*

*Honestly code readability is very subjective, if you were looking for something like a switch-case logic in python, Your code would look like -*

```py
def foo (a=None, b=None, c=None):
  match a, b, c:
    # Add all your cases
    case None, None, _:
      # Do Your Operations and Return
      return
    case other:
      print("Other Cases")
```

This is one of the best features that got released with 3.10. Hope this helps you.

Comment: It's a cute feature, familiar to F# and OCAML programmers, but I do not find this to be more readable than the if/elif/else chain.  One of the benefits of Python is that most code can be read like prose.  This does not.

Comment: @TimRoberts Totally agree on the fact that it isn't very readable. But a switch-case feature was long pending in python, to help on scenarios where you're match multiple arguments on a case basis. Match is definitely on a replacement for if-else, it's just a viable alternative for people who find a use for it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you might find the new pattern matching syntax to be what you want (requires `python >= 3.10`, [spec in PEP634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/), [tutorial in PEP636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636)).

```py
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    match a, b, c:
        case a_, None, None:
            r = 1 * a_
        case None, b_, None:
            r = 2 * b_
        # add more patterns here
        case _:
            r = None
    return r

foo(a=1)  # 1
foo(b=5)  # 10
foo(a=0, b=0)  # None # no pattern for a and b
foo(c=8)  # None # no pattern for c
```

**NB.** the same is achievable with if/elif/else.

```py
def bar(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    if a is not None and b is None and c is None:
        r = 1 * a
    elif a is None and b is not None and c is None:
        r = 2 * b
    # add more elifs here
    else:
        r = None
    return r
```